# ConcurrentModificationException not thrown consistently

Tags: java, iterator

Using `list.remove((Object)93)` causes a `ConcurrentModificationException` in this example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(14);
list.add(2);
list.add(44);
list.add(41);
list.add(93);
list.add(20);

for(Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();it.hasNext();) {
    list.remove((Object)93);
    it.next();
}
System.out.println(list);
```

However, when I wrap `list.remove((Object)93)` in a if statement, it doesn't cause any errors. Why?

```
for(Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();it.hasNext();) {
    int num = it.next();
    if(num == 93) {
        list.remove((Object)93);
    }
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate, at least not to the linked question. This question *specifically* talks about removing an item using `list.remove()` while iterating over the list, not `it.remove()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first example you get the `ConcurrentModificationException` at the first iteration and this is expected since you modified the list while iterating with iterator.

In the second example after removing the `93` from your `ArrayList` the `it.next()` will not even be called because `hasNext` will return false - see the implementation of `ArrayList.Itr::hasNext` :

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.cursor != ArrayList.this.size;
}
```

it only check if `ArrayList` size is different than the cursor. In your example the `93` element is placed in the last but one place. After removing the `93` element the size will decrease by one so `it.next()` will evaluate to `false` and `it.next` will not be called and no exception is thrown.

This is a coincidence that you placed `93` at the one before last place so you did not receive the exception. Try to add another value to `ArrayList` after `93` and `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown like in the first example.